# SendMail: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail, dovecot

So I've installed Sendmail service, Dovecot and SquirrelMail in my server. I arrived to receive mails from local clients (different hosts in the same newtork). But I cannot send mails from server to clients, and also when a client host try to send mail to another client of this server ,the server recieve it but it cannot relay it to the other client. (NB: I'm working only in a local network). This is the error from my mail.log:

> Nov 30 15:34:10 dev sendmail[5620]: uAUFY8Jl005620: from=*dev*, size=4, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201611301534.uAUFY8Jl005620@dev.**localhost**>, relay=root@localhost
>   Nov 30 15:34:10 *dev* sendmail[5620]: uAUFY8Jl005620: to=FatimaZ@test.test2.fr, ctladdr=dev (1000/1000), delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30004, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
>   Nov 30 15:40:01 *dev* **sm-msp-queue[5802]**: uAUFQnYE005516: to=FatimaZ@test.test2.fr, ctladdr=dev (1000/1000), delay=00:13:12,

And whene client1 try to send to client2 , I get this error

> Nov 30 15:57:52 *dev* sm-mta[5853]: uAUFvQin005853: client1@test.test2.fr ... User unknown
>   Nov 30 15:57:57 *dev* sm-mta[5853]: uAUFvQin005853: from=client1@test.test2.fr, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=SMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=client2.test.test2.fr [192.168.0.3]

This is how my /etc/hosts file looks like:

```
 127.0.0.1       dev.localhost dev
 127.0.1.1       dev   
 192.168.0.1     dnsServer1.test.test2.fr dnsServer1 
 192.168.0.1     mail.test.test2.fr       mail
```

And the /etc/mail/local-host-names :

```
localhost
192.168.0.1
mail.test.test2.fr
test.test2.fr
dev
```

I'm in ubuntu 14. Thank you for your help.

Extra info from comments:

```
$netstat -ant | grep :25 
tcp 0 0 192.168.0.1:25 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 
tcp6 0 0 ::1:25 :::* LISTEN
```

Comment: What is reported by `netstat -ant | grep :25`?

Comment: hello @AndrzejA.Filip  :  netstat -ant | grep :25  reported                                                                            tcp           0              0 192.168.0.1:25          0.0.0.0:*                LISTEN                                                                                        tcp6         0              0 ::1:25                          :::*                        LISTEN

Comment: Have you checked sendmail log files? e.g. for reports about overload safeguards

Comment: this is the last report i've got in my logfiles while trying to send an email from my server to a host client

Comment: Nov 30 15:34:10 dev sendmail[5620]: uAUFY8Jl005620: from=dev, size=4, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201611301534.uAUFY8Jl005620@dev.localhost>, relay=root@localhost
Nov 30 15:34:10 dev sendmail[5620]: uAUFY8Jl005620: to=FatimaZ@test.test2.fr, ctladdr=dev (1000/1000), delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30004, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
Nov 30 15:40:01 dev sm-msp-queue[5802]: uAUFQnYE005516: to=FatimaZ@test.test2.fr, ctladdr=dev (1000/1000), delay=00:13:12,

Answer (score 4):

Sendmail passes messages submitted by "send via command line sendmail" to local sendmail daemon listening at 127.0.0.1:25.

It seems that you sendmail listens only on IPv4 192.168.0.1:25 (local network?) and IPv6 ::1:25 (any).  Most likely you wanted to accept incoming TCP connections only from local network.

Fix `DAEMON_OPTIONS` in your `sendmail.mc` file. Add listening on 127.0.0.1 or use listening on IPv4 "any".

---

In your `sendmail.mc` add the second DAEMON_OPTIONS listed below.
Recompile `sendmail.mc` into `sendmail.cf` and restart (or HUP) sendmail daemon.

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Addr=192.168.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA-loopback')dnl
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to do " listening on IPV4 -any- " ? but are u sur this is the solution for this problem? because all i want is to be able to send email from my server "sendmail" to other hosts in this local network , and thank you

Comment: What's reported by 1) `grep DAEMON_OPTIONS /etc/mail/sendmail.mc` 2) `grep DaemonPortOptions /dev/mail/sendmail.cf`

Comment: grep DAEMON_OPTIONS /etc/mail/sendmail.mc reported 5 lines

Comment: DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Addr=192.168.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl

Comment: DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=init6, Name=MTA-v6, Port=smtp, Addr=::1')dnl

Comment: dnl # DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet, Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl

Comment: dnl # DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MSP-v6, Port=submission, M=EA, Adrr=::1')dnl

Comment: DEAMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet, Name=MSP-v6, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl

Comment: and the second one : grep DaemonPortOptions /dev/mail/sendmail.cf

Comment: DaemonPortOptions=Port=smtp, Addr=192.168.0.1, Name=MTA

Comment: DaemonPortOptions=Family=inet6, Name=MTA-v6, Port=smtp, Addr=::1

Comment: DaemonPortOptions=Family=inet, Name=MSP-v4, Port=submission, M=EA, Addr=127.0.0.1

Comment: : hello again , i'm sorry for being late , i'v tried adding this line DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA-loopback')dnl in my file sendmail.mc but this doesn't work :( i still have the same error in my log file saying that the other host(client2) is "User uknown" ...