# dovecot SquirrelMail w/ sendmail on Fedora Connection refused by [127.0.0.1] when sending

Tags: smtp, sendmail, spamassassin

We use Fedora 25 with sendmail-8.15.2-8.fc25.x86_64 and whilst sending messages via SquirrelMail it takes quite a while. These logs appear:

```
delay=00:00:15, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=46987, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
```

I tried [this suggestion](https://www.dolejarz.com/sendmail-deferred-connection-refused-127-0-0-1/):

```
# SMTP daemon options
O DaemonPortOptions=Family=inet, Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=XX.XX.XX.XX
O DaemonPortOptions=Family=inet, Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1
O DaemonPortOptions=Family=inet, Name=MSP-v4, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=127.0.0.1
```

And:

```
cat /etc/hosts.allow
ALL : 127.0.0.1
```

Firewalld seems ok too:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --list-all
[...]
  services: samba imaps pop3s http ssh nfs samba-client smtp dhcpv6-client mysql cockpit https vnc-server postgresql ipp-client mdns ipp dns 

rich rules:
        rule family="ipv4" source address="218.65.30.108" reject
        rule family="ipv4" source address="72.9.101.182" reject
```

Anything else to check? The mail eventually DOES go out. Takes almost a minute.

Edit: using the [suggestion here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/sendmail-is-only-accepting-connections-from.html), I was at least able to get mails to go out. Now it seems SpamAssassin is slowing things down w/ Pyzor being a culprit.

```
Jul 13 23:03:24 storm sendmail[14504]: v6E33EOQ014504: Authentication-Warning: our-domain: apache set sender to me@our-domain using -f
Jul 13 23:03:39 storm sendmail[14504]: v6E33EOQ014504: from=me@our-domain, size=535, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<9ca00a710c6bfad3d60dd424cd79ac19.squirrel@our-domain>, relay=apache@localhost
Jul 13 23:04:05 storm sendmail[14629]: v6E33ddm014629: from=<me@our-domain>, size=779, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<9ca00a710c6bfad3d60dd424cd79ac19.squirrel@our-domain>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-loopback, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Jul 13 23:04:05 storm sendmail[14629]: v6E33ddm014629: Milter insert (1): header: X-Virus-Scanned: clamav-milter 0.99.2 at our-domain
Jul 13 23:04:05 storm sendmail[14629]: v6E33ddm014629: Milter insert (1): header: X-Virus-Status: Clean
Jul 13 23:04:05 storm spamd[13378]: spamd: connection from localhost [::1]:48316 to port 783, fd 5
Jul 13 23:04:05 storm spamd[13378]: spamd: using default config for root: /home/spamd/user_prefs
Jul 13 23:04:05 storm spamd[13378]: spamd: processing message <9ca00a710c6bfad3d60dd424cd79ac19.squirrel@our-domain> for root:1001
Jul 13 23:04:20 storm spamd[13378]: spamd: clean message (-101.5/5.0) for root:1001 in 15.0 seconds, 1193 bytes.
Jul 13 23:04:20 storm spamd[13378]: spamd: result: . -101 - ALL_TRUSTED,BAYES_00,PYZOR_CHECK,USER_IN_WHITELIST scantime=15.0,size=1193,user=root,uid=1001,required_score=5.0,rhost=localhost,raddr=::1,rport=48316,mid=<9ca00a710c6bfad3d60dd424cd79ac19.squirrel@our-domain>,bayes=0.000000,autolearn=no autolearn_force=no
Jul 13 23:04:20 storm sendmail[14629]: v6E33ddm014629: Milter add: header: X-Spam-Status: No, score=-101.5 required=5.0 tests=ALL_TRUSTED,BAYES_00,\n\tPYZOR_CHECK,USER_IN_WHITELIST autolearn=no autolearn_force=no version=3.4.1
Jul 13 23:04:20 storm sendmail[14629]: v6E33ddm014629: Milter add: header: X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.1 (2015-04-28) on\n\tour-domain
Jul 13 23:04:20 storm sendmail[14504]: v6E33EOQ014504: to=me@our-domain, ctladdr=me@our-domain (16836/16836), delay=00:01:06, xdelay=00:00:41, mailer=relay, pri=30535, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (v6E33ddm014629 Message accepted for delivery)
Jul 13 23:04:20 storm spamd[13309]: prefork: child states: II
Jul 13 23:04:20 storm spamd[13378]: spamd: connection from localhost [::1]:48320 to port 783, fd 5
Jul 13 23:04:20 storm spamd[13378]: spamd: using default config for spamd: /home/spamd/user_prefs
Jul 13 23:04:20 storm spamd[13378]: spamd: processing message <9ca00a710c6bfad3d60dd424cd79ac19.squirrel@our-domain> for spamd:1001
```

Comment: Is sendmail daemon up and running?  (`ps`, `netstat`)  Have sendmail logged successful startup in the log file?

Comment: Yes and yes, email is flowing, just the sending via SquirrelMail is slow.

Comment: Does sendmail report overload in the log file?  Sendmail may start to refuse incoming cnnections when system local is too high (see `RefuseLA`).

Answer (score 0):

Possible explanations

1. sendmail daemon is not running
   use `ps` (`ps auxw | grep sendmail`), check log files
2. sendmail daemon refuses new SMTP connections due to too high system load
   use `uptime`, check log files
3. sendmail daemon is not listeting on 127.0.0.1interface/all interfaces
   use `netstat` (`netstat -ant | grep :25` on Debian)
4. incoming connections are blocked by firewall or tcpwrappers
   AFAIK **most** sendmail installation nowdays are not compiled with tcpwrappers support

Comment: 1)  ps auxw | grep sendmail 
root      zz  0.0  0.0 111672  zz ?        Ss   16:53   0:00 sendmail: accepting connections  
smmsp     yy  0.0  0.0  84928  zz ?        Ss   16:53   0:00 sendmail:  Queue runner@01 for /clientmqueue  
root     xx  0.0  0.0 111672  zz ?    S    21:13   0:00 sendmail: startup with xxx.yyy.co  
2) :14:55 up 57 days,  5:03,  7 users,  load average: 0.20, 0.18, 0.09  
3) netstat -ant | grep :25  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.0:25            0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN  
tcp        0      0 our-external-ip:25        0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN  
4) I showed firewalld rules

Comment: Hm now seeing messages like: Authentication-Warning: ourdomain: apache set sender to me@mydomain using -f and no mail going out via Squirrelmail & delay=05:26:50, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=822734, relay=[127.0.0.1], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 issues here. Not sure why email from outside the server was being rejected but I followed [this suggestion](https://serverfault.com/questions/818210/sendmail-connection-refused-by-127-0-0-1/818250#818250):

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Addr=192.168.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA-loopback')dnl
```

And then, for the slow SpamAssassin & sending of emails via SquirrelMail, the first DNS server listed by NetworkManager (sym linked in /etc/resolv.conf) was an IP that is not supposed to be used by computers within our IP space. Once I changed it, web mail sending was just a second or 2.